# Little bug with searchview.setOnQueryTextListener, i can't see immediately the result

Tags: android, listener, android-arrayadapter, searchview

I want print the result of research only if the written characters in 'searchview' element are more of 3.
In this way i can take the data when i have more of 3 written characters, but i can see the result only if i write another 1 characters.
I need to see the result when the written characters are 4 and don't 5.
How can I see the result when the characters are 4?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    final String[] from = new String[] {"title"};
    final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

    myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);
    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                 return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if(s.length() > 3) {
                    new Data().execute(s);
                }

                MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{ BaseColumns._ID, "Title" });
                for (int i=0; i<strArrData.length; i++) {
                    if (strArrData[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toLowerCase()))
                        mc.addRow(new Object[] {i, strArrData[i]});
                }
                myAdapter.changeCursor(mc);

                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
                searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edit:

```
        myAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, "Title"});
                for (int i = 0; i < strArrData.length; i++) {
                    mc.addRow(new Object[]{i, strArrData[i]});
                }
                return mc;
            }
        });
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: you dont need any `OnQueryTextListener`, all you need to do is to call `setSuggestionsAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: How do you put in correctly the data in here? myAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return null;
            }
        });

Comment: return right cursor from `runQuery` method

Comment: How should I do? 'Return cursor;'? I found an error: 'incompatible types'.

Comment: just return your `MatrixCursor` here

Comment: I tried, but I can not get the desired result: I always see the result at the fifth letter instead of the fourth.

Comment: final MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, "Title"});
        myAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return mc.getChanges(constraint.toString());
            }
        });=> this can't work why?

Comment: inside `runQuery` just create `MatrixCursor`, fill it with data and return

Comment: create new `MatrixCursor` inside `runQuery`, fill it with data based on `runQuery` method parameter and return that cursor

Comment: See my edit. I try to do it, but i found again the same error of beginning.

Comment: what error?  your FQP does not filter anything

Comment: I understand that you told me to do it this way. If it is wrong you can show me how would you do? Really I am now a bit confused ...

Comment: try [this](http://pastebin.com/KhbkZ3ZY), it will explain how `FilterQueryProvider` works